# Sphere inside a pyramid

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A spherical ball of radius $1$ rests inside a holder in the shape of an inverted pyramid. The pyramid has a horizontal square top and its other faces are equilateral triangles. It is large enough to enclose the ball.
How far is the centre of the ball above the apex $X$ of the pyramid?

diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c6js.jpg

(Answer: $\sqrt 3$)

So far, I tried making a triangle $OAX$, where $O$ is the centre of the circle and $A$ is the point where the sphere meets one of the triangular faces. I have said that ∠$OAX$ is a right angle and that ∠$OXA$ is $30$º but that gives the incorrect answer of $2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not even close to an expert, but I think you meant OXA is roughly 30 this makes OAX roughly 60 if you want to form a right triangle. AOX is the right angle if anything forms one in that set.

Comment: Yeah that would yield the correct answer, but I'm not sure why the angles are have those values as opposed to the values that I set.

Comment: `∠OXA is 30º` No, it is not $\,30^\circ\,$. Hint: let $Y,Z$ be the intersections of plane $OAX$ with the respective opposite sides of the square base. Triangle $\triangle XYZ$ is isosceles (though not equilateral), and the cross section of the sphere is its inscribed circle.

Comment: @oscquito , I didn't say it would actually. $\angle OXA+\angle OAX+\angle AOX=180\deg$ if we talk a planar right triangle. Like I said, I'm not close to an expert though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made the mistake in thinking the cross section is also an equilateral triangle. Actually, it's isosceles.

---

Let $s$ be the side length of the pyramid. Then the triangular vertical cross section you're interested in has base $s$, and sides $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}s$ (The sides of length $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}s$ are the altitudes of opposite equilateral faces of the pyramid).

Let this triangular cross section have its vertices other than $X$ labelled $Y$ and $Z$. Let the midpoint of $YZ$ be $M$.

Then triangle $XYM$ is right-angled with hypotenuse $XY=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}s$ and base $MY=\frac{s}{2}$.

Now notice that $XYM$ is similar to $OAX$ (share an angle and both are right-angled) and hence use the ratio of the lengths to deduce $OX=\sqrt 3$.